# "\definecolor" changes the color theme of beamer

Tags: beamer, color, themes

Using [`\definecolor{darkred}{rgb}{0.55, 0.0, 0.0}`](http://latexcolor.com/), the color theme of beamer has become darker. Why is this? How to avoid it?

[image: beamer-definecolor]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usecolortheme{beaver}

\definecolor{darkred}{rgb}{0.55, 0.0, 0.0}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{}
  Color Test
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The colortheme beaver uses a color named darkred, so basically you are overwriting it.
If you change the name of your color (for example to "Darkred") everything should work